# Add a value besides a certain string within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where, whenever a certain string is present, I would like a specific value to be appended to this.

df

```
id  test
aa  5
aa  4
bb  3
cc  2
dd  1
aa  0
```

**Desired**

```
type   id   test
1000   aa   5
1000   aa   4
500    bb   3
1200   cc   2
200    dd   1
1000   aa   0

I would like to append 1000 to aa
500 to bb, 1200 to cc, and 200 to dd
```

**Doing**

I believe I have to create a dictionary key match pairing with this particular post. I am not sure how to keep the other remaining columns as well in the output. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
test= {'aa' : 1000, 'bb' : 500, 'cc' : 1200, 'dd' : 200}
```

Comment: If some problem, let me know.

Comment: ok I realize solution now, I believe I had it first time. Thank you

Comment: No problem, happy coding!